# PHP - DOMXpath does not return any nodes when it should

Tags: php, dom

I am pulling HTML from Selenium, and then extracting data from the HTML using Xpaths.

This is the Xpath:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/ul/li/div[1]/h3/a
```

This is my code:

```
$data = $webdriver->getPageSource();
d($data, $urltemplate);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
                    $doc->loadHTML($data);
$xp = "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/ul/li/div[1]/h3/a";
            $xpatho = new DOMXpath($doc);
 $elementsn =  $xpatho->query($xp);
d(get_class($elementsn),$elementsn->count(),$xp,$name);
// d() is a custom function like var_dump().
```

I always get $elementsn->count() = 0.

This is $data:

https://pastebin.com/ahuvkJfN

I am trying to extract those strings like "NAD M10 BLUOS...", "NAD M12 DIRECT DIGITAL..." and so on...

I saved the HTML into a file, and opened it in my browser. I am attaching screenshot of what data I was looking to retrieve (highlighted in blue):
[image]

Basically, the HTML page is a product listing, and I am looking to extract all the product names. To confirm, I used Chrome Developer tools, and used the copy full Xpath function. I have the following Xpaths for some of the product names:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div[1]/h3/a
/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/div[1]/h3/a
```

I would guess that this would generalise to:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/ul/li/div[1]/h3/a
```

However, I keep on getting a DOMNodeList with count = 0. Why is this so, and how can I check what the error is, if any?

P.S.: This is the original webpage: http://lenbrook.com.sg/3-shop-by-brand#/page-4/price-49-8667

Comment: One thing to check with web pages is to save the HTML to a file and open it in a text editor.  Try and find the text you are looking for.  If the text isn't there, there is a good chance it's loaded by Javascript when the page is displayed in a browser.

Comment: @NigelRen it's there! I said: "I saved the HTML into a file, and opened it in my browser. I am attaching screenshot of what data I was looking to retrieve (highlighted in blue)". This HTML was extracted from Selenium, which means all browser rendering has already been done. I pasted it to https://pastebin.com/ahuvkJfN. The data I need is there... That's why I find it really strange....

Comment: forgodsakehold - accordingto nigels tipps -  If the text isn't there, there is a good chance it's loaded by Javascript when the page is displayed in a browser - it is allways a good idea to investigate the target with Chrome ... but as its stands now: you have come along with a solution.  I am glad bout that. Keep up the great work !!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `$xp`

```
$xp = '//a[@class="product_link"]/text()'
```